# How to get a loop to load movieclips with eventlisteners

Tags: for-loop, actionscript-3, actionscript, addeventlistener

I wanted the scene load 5 different movie clips (named B1-B5). Each movie clip is placed on a specific x and y. Each movie clip grows/shrinks on roll over/roll out....

I got the code working by typing everything out and duplicating each section per time but it's messy and I'd like to clean up the code by getting a loop to do it (if it's possible?).

This is the code that works but I'd have to duplicate it per movie clip (changing the obvious bits)...

```
var scene1:MovieClip = new B1();
    addChild(scene1);
    scene1.x = 170.30;
    scene1.y = 231.15;
    scene1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onRollOverEvent1);
    scene1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onRollOutEvent1);

function onRollOverEvent1(e:MouseEvent) {
    scene1.width=25.9;
    scene1.height=25;
 }

function onRollOutEvent1(e:MouseEvent) {
    scene1.width = 20.9;
    scene1.height = 20;
 }
```

Below is what I've tried out but have been stuck for a good while...

```
for (var i:int=1; i<5; i++){
    var scene[i]:MovieClip = new "B"+i();
    addChild("scene"+i);
    //var scene[i]:MovieClip = new B[i]();
    scene[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onRollOverEvent);
    scene[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onRollOutEvent)

    function onRollOverEvent(e:MouseEvent) {
    scene[i].width=25.9;
    scene[i].height=25;
 }
    function onRollOutEvent(e:MouseEvent) {
    scene[i].width = 20.9;
    scene[i].height = 20;
 }
}

scene1.x = 170.30;
scene1.y = 231.15;
scene2.x = 284.30;
scene2.y = 250.75;
scene3.x = 377.30;
scene3.y = 280.15;  
scene4.x = 444.30;
scene4.y = 321.15;
scene5.x = 196.30;
scene5.y = 172.15;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets go through your mistakes.

```
new "B"+i();
```

*At the very best* that translates to calling a number **i** as function and adding the result to "B" as a **String**. But even **new "B1"()** is not the same as **new B1()**. There is, in fact, a method **getDefinitionByName(..)** that allows to address a class via its name, but I don't recommend to use it because it is advanced topic.

```
var scene[i]:MovieClip
```

You just cannot define variables **scene1**, **scene2**, etc this way. The closest thing you can actually devise is the square bracket notation: **this["scene" + i] = ...**.

```
addChild("scene"+i);
```

The argument must be a **DisplayObject** instance, not a **String**.

```
for (...)
{
    ...
    function onRollOverEvent(e:MouseEvent)
    ...
}
```

Do not define functions inside other functions or loops.

```
scene[i].width = 20.9;
scene[i].height = 20;
```

By the end of your loop **i** will be equal to **5**, so, what do you think such a record will address?

Then, the solution.

When you come to scaling your working solution to multiple instances, you are to go algorithmic. Loops and **Array**s are your friends.

```
// Lets devise a list of classes and (x,y) coordinates.
var Designs:Array = [
    null, // the 0-th element
    {id:B1, x:170, y:230},
    {id:B2, x:285, y:250},
];

for (var i:int = 1; i < Design.length; i++)
{
    // Retrieve a record for the future object.
    var aDesign:Object = Designs[i];

    // Get a reference to the object's class.
    var aClass:Class = aDesign.id;

    // Create the object. Yes, you CAN omit () with
    // the "new" operator if there are no mandatory arguments.
    var aThing:Movieclip = new aClass;

    // Set coordinates from the design record.
    aThing.x = aDesign.x;
    aThing.y = aDesign.y;

    // Add to the display list.
    addChild(aThing);

    // Subscribe the event handlers.
    aThing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onOver);
    aThing.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onOut);

    // Save the object's reference for the later use.
    // If you'd need to address, say, 3rd object,
    // you do it as following:
    // Designs[3].instance
    aDesign.instance = aThing;
}

function onOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // You subscribed all of the objects to this one event handler.
    // This is the correct way to learn, which one of the objects
    // is under the mouse and is dispatching the said event.
    var aThing:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    // Change the object's size.
    aThing.width = 26;
    aThing.height = 25;
}

function onOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Get the source of the dispatched event.
    var aThing:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

    // Change the object's size.
    aThing.width = 21;
    aThing.height = 20;
}
```

Comment: Hi Organis, sorry for the super slow reply. I only just remembered my password x.x! Thank you so much! My code is working and whilst remembering my password I managed to get the other parts of my code working. I did try some of the stuff you listed here but didn't understand how to piece it together and since I've tried so much combinations, it wasn't worth flooding all my attempts here. Thanks to what you've typed here, I've confirmed where my error was.